# Как проверить регулярным выражением конец и начало строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```js
var link = '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=https://www.google.com/">';
link.match(/^ ">$/ig);
```

Как с помощью регулярного выражения достать `https://www.google.com/`?

Comment: как доставание `https://www.google.com/` связано с проверкой начала и конца?

Comment: @Grundy, я думал, что я могу проверить начало на URL= и конец на ">

И достать все, что между ними

Comment: Начало строки - первый символ (вернее, даже то, что перед ним), конец строки - последний. А вы хотите достать часть строки из середины.

Answer (score 3):

Можно очень просто:

```
var link = '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=https://www.google.com/">';
link.match(/URL=(.+)">$/i);
```

Результат:

```
array(
  0 =>  URL=https://www.google.com/">
  1 =>  https://www.google.com/
)
```

Вот хорошая шпаргалка: https://www.exlab.net/files/tools/sheets/regexp/regexp.png

```
Начало строки: '^'
Конец строки: '$'
```

В даном случае не нужна проверка на начало строки.

Comment: Вообще, вопрос по JavaScript, а не по PHP. Зачем в ответе `preg_match('/URL=(.+)">$/i', $input_line, $output_array);`?

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score -1):

Тут нужен предпросмотр:

```js
link.match(/(?<=URL=).+(?=")/)[0]
```

Можно ещё через `split()`:

```js
link.split(/URL=|"/)[4]
```

И ещё можно через `replace()`:

```js
link.replace(/.+URL=|">/g,"")
```